# django: very slow POST request

Tags: python, django, http-post

I have a problem with POST requests on Django. When I'm sending a POST request it takes like 12-13 sec to proceed it. When sending The same request, but using GET method, everything is ok.

I created a test view, which does nothing but sending a GET or POST request:
http://celeb-birthdays.clearsoft.pl/star-birthdays/empty/

YSlow shows that GET is loaded in 0.2s, but it takes over 12s to load POST.
The problem doesn't reproduce on localhost, only on the remote server.

Even more interesting is that adding DebugToolbarMiddleware fixes the problem.

Any ideas what could be the reason or what to do next?

**Edit:**

As @Yuji Tomita said, the server indeed wasn't terminating the response until timeout. Replacing "Connection: keep-alive" with "Connection: close" in http request header helps, but it's not a valid solution to this problem...

I also found out that it loads quickly when HTTP response has attribute 'Content-Length' set. So I added 'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware' middleware, which gzip-s the response and sets the Content-Length. It's not SO wrong, since HTTP compression is recommended, nevertheless it's still just a workaround, because lack of 'Content-Length' attribute is not the cause of the issue.

Comment: what are you doing with the post request? Show us the view's code. On the other hand, how do you have django configured? apache + wsgi + django?

Comment: From my location, ~350 ms on post / get. Is this a YSlow problem?

Comment: @tiagoboldt I was a bit unprecise, the view does nothing. Just render_to_response("empty.html"), empty.html is on the link I wrote. Clicking GET or POST button "reloads" the page, sending a variable through GET or POST.

Comment: @Yuji Tomita, hmm that's interesting... it's not YSlow problem, 'cos I can see the delay even without any tools. The html loads quickly, but the preloader is visible for the next 12-13s. onload function is also called after such a long time.

Comment: how's your django configured? (running platform, server, so on)

Comment: how you connect your apache to django? are there any additional rewrites/filters/content filters configures?

Comment: I give up, but I see the timeout as well. It happens at exactly the keep-alive of 12s, and when looking at the raw response, it's returning `favicon.ico` 404 message at 12s. It makes me think the server isn't terminating the first chunked response and upon timeout, the browser finally does the favicon request. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, it's apache + wsgi + django; Python 2.6.2, Django 1.2.5, rather default configuration.

Context processors:
django.core.context_processors.i18n
django.core.context_processors.media
django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages
django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth
django.core.context_processors.csrf
django.core.context_processors.debug

I can show full settings if it helps...